# Cannot store Greek in datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2

I have a serious problem with my google app engine app. Until now, anything I store on database, was in English. Now I have to store few things in Greek and when I try to retrieve it later from the database, I have a `u'\u039a\u03b1\u03b9\u03c1\u03cc\u03c2'` instead of the string.

Until now, when I wanted to put something on the html I used the following one

```
error = unicode(error,"utf-8")
```

But I tried it to put it right before I store it on the data, but doesn't help

**Edit:**

I just see something that confused me more. I get those strings from an html form. I have many inputs where the Greek works great. But those that create the problem are on a `"select"` tag where I get a list of all the selections. The other inputs are stored in the database in Greek without any problem.

**Edit 2:**

I want to edit something from the comments. I made a mistake. If I print the variable, I can see the string without a problem. But if I `self.response.out.write(thestring)`, I see the `%CE%9A%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%BD%CF%89%CE%BD%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC`

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Python 3.x handles unicode differently than 2.x.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure Python's repl doesn't decode unicode when it is pretty printing (the `u"..."` form). Does it work when you `print` it? If not, you must set the encoding of your output file (say, `sys.stdout`).

Comment: I have python 2.7. Also if I try to print it, it looks like this %CE%9A%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%BD%CF%89%CE%BD%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC

Comment: Don't have much experience with GAE, but I had the same problem storing Unicode text in MySQL, which was solved by setting "characterEncoding" and "characterSetResult" in the connection string to "utf8" for both, and setting "useUnicode" to "true". Might not be your issue at all, but I tore my hair out for 2 weeks thinking it was an encoding issue coming from another system, only to find a much simpler fix.

Comment: Okay. The problem is that you need do one or both of a) decode the string, or b) set the output encoding of your file handle. I don't remember much Python these days, however! Best of luck.

Comment: Hello @ChrisDoggett. Seems you have a similar problem, could you please provide an example as an answer, so I will try it and if it will solve my problem, I will choose yours as a best answer?

Comment: @Tasos Since It's not printing *any* unicode, my hunch is that it's a problem with  `Python <-> output`, not  `database <-> Python`. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @jpaugh I made a mistake. Please see the edit2 in my post. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can store and retrieve Greek in google app engine but it didn't work for me either until I did this:

`name = unicode(form.name.data, "utf8")`

I can store greek in google app engine so why not do like I do. It's easier said than done but use utf-8 everywhere and then it will work. You will need the code for your webpages like so:

`<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

You can also need to instruct your input form to encode it as utf-8, but I don't do it with appengine and still I can store greek. I only found this experimentally, if you want the theory you can read [these slides](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/).

Comment: I can store in greek too but only simple inputs. If I retrieve data from "select" html tags, those data stored like I said on the first post.