# python encoding characters in jinja2

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, character-encoding, jinja2

It's a similar one with one of my [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945099/cannot-store-greek-in-datastore). I try to solve all the side effects of the first one.

I have stored few non-ascii characters on my database. If I make few "encoding-decoding" stuffs, I managed to work with the database queries. But I have another problem.

If I use the

```
self.response.out.write(mystring)
```

in one of my entities ( looks like this -> u'\u0395\u03c0\u03b9\u03c3\u03c4\u03ae\u03bc\u03b5\u03c2')

I can see it without any problem. But, I have a javascript which create a graph and needs a list with those strings. If I pass the list to the javascript like it is from the database, the javascript doesn't work at all. If I use the

```
tag2 = tag.encode("utf-8")
```

for every entity on the list and then pass the new list, I see all the non-ascii characters like this one -> ÎÏÎ¹ÏÏÎ®Î¼ÎµÏ